# TensorFlow install error with Anaconda using Python 3.5 (Windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am working with Python 3.5 and I  installed TensorFlow in windows 10 using Anaconda.
I got following error:

> **; TypeError: 'module' object is not callable**

```
File "D:/Thèse1/LSTM/code/code_python/LSTM-Human-Activity-Recognition-master/lstm.py", line 114, in LSTM_Network

outputs, _ = tf.contrib.rnn(lsmt_layers, feature_mat, dtype=tf.float32)   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please restructure your question and make it more readable. You should report what you want to obtain, what you tried and the error that you get.

Comment: [`tf.contrib.rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn) is a module, which the error message helpfully points out.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because you are trying to call a module object as a function. In particular, `tf.contrib.rnn` is the TensorFlow module which contains all the RNN cells. You can find the related documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.rnn).

If you want to use an LSTM cell you need to use an [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell).